# configure//make error on Ubuntu Pjsip PJproject

Tags: sip, rtp, pjsip, opus

I am trying to extract *opus rtp packets* and convert them into wav format from the pcap file. In order to do so, I installed *pjproject2.6* using the following commands:

```
cd pjproject2.6/
./configure
make dep && make
```

After the last command, I ran into the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/cmath:47:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/math.h:36,
                 from ../../yuv/source/compare.cc:14:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_abs.h: In function ‘constexpr long double std::abs(long double)’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_abs.h:78:22: error: x87 register return with x87 disabled
   abs(long double __x)
                      ^
    /home/administrator/pjproject-2.6/build/rules.mak:178: recipe for target 'output/libyuv-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/compare.o' failed
make[3]: *** [output/libyuv-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/compare.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/administrator/pjproject-2.6/third_party/build/yuv'
Makefile:100: recipe for target 'libyuv-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a' failed
make[2]: *** [libyuv-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/administrator/pjproject-2.6/third_party/build/yuv'
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/administrator/pjproject-2.6/third_party/build'
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem, have you solved it?

Comment: Since i couldnt resolve it, Had to delete the entire PJSIP installation and re-install...